# Range.Find straight from MSDN not working, Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, msdn

I have been stuck on this for hours now, and .find seemed to be working for me in earlier versions of the same program.  I'm not sure what version of excel the file was saved as earlier when range.find was working (either 2010 or 2003), but it is now not working in Excel 2010.  In order to eliminate other parts of my code as the source of the error, I literally copied and pasted the following from MSDN into my editor, put it in its own subroutine, declared the variables, and still got the same "Application-defined or object-defined error" when the code was run.  Here is the code that produced the error on line , I have noted where I deviated from what was on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Sub StraitFromMSDN()
'Only line that was changed:
'With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
With ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a500")
    'These two lines were added:
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    'Error occurs on the following line:
    Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = 5
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?  I am relatively new to vba so it is possible I am missing something simple.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I still get the error when I take the lower part out:

```
Sub StraitFromMSDN()
Dim c As Range
With ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a500")

    'Error occurs here:
    Set c = .Find(What:=2, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is an error in the line `Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress`   In VBA `And` does not "short-circuit" (both arguments are always evaluated), so even if `c` is `Nothing` it will still try to evaluate `c.Address` (and this will throw an error when c is Nothing).  This needs to be split into two tests - first for c then for the Address. See (eg) http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Worth adding: typically this is not a problem, because FindNext() will wrap back once it has found the last search value in the range (and so c will never be Nothing), but in your case you're removing each value as you go, so after the last value there's no other value to warap back to. In this particular case you don't even need to track the `Address` - that's really only useful if you need to detect when the Find wraps bacxk to the first cell.

Comment: Quick fix for what Tim mentioned would be to just change 'Not c Is Nothing' to 'c <> ""'. I tested the above code (with the adjustment I mentioned) and it worked without an error. I couldn't replicate the error you describe.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did not know that about "short-circuiting" in VBA (and it is interesting that code on MSDN would make this mistake), but the error was occurring before that portion of the code and I still get the error with that part removed.

Comment: I can't replicate that behaviour.  What kind of content do you have in A1:A500 ?  Any merged cells etc ?  Maybe try that same code in a band-new workbook.

Comment: @D_Zab Thank you for the fix and for testing, (I now know it probably has something to do with my machine or settings etc.).  Do you know of any such settings that could cause this discrepancy in results?

Comment: @TimWilliams LOL, a new workbook didn't work, but restarting excel did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Excel fixed the problem.  It was a glitch plain and simple, not sure what caused the behavior though.  Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub StraitFromMSDN()

Dim c As Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a500")
    If Not .Find(What:=2, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then 'test if there is any value you are looking for
        Set c = .Find(What:=2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

This will only find ONE cell containing value 2. If you want to find all of them, let me know, there is a bit more complex code behind that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the check if it is there, but the problem was just a glitch.  I should have answered my question earlier so people wouldn't waste more time on it. +1 sorry.